# How to do loginscreen in android using sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am try to write a simple program to loginScreen.In first screen user enter the user_name and password if username and password match in the database then open the next screen otherwise first you enter the your detail then signup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is your question try to enter data in database fetch it and match it with the data entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.For failur condition you just reload the page and dispay a textview for signing up

[Having trouble creating an Android Login Page with Intents & Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772746/having-trouble-creating-an-android-login-page-with-intents-activities)